# If 2 straight lines have gradients m1 and m2, what is the angle between them?

Tags: geometry

I know how to find the angle between 2 lines using arctan(m) for each line and subtracting the values, but how would you use this if the gradients are not known, and no other information is given about the lines themselves?

Answer (score 0):

What information is given? It's hard to solve a problem with no information. But yes, the abstract solution is

theta = arctan(m1) - arctan(m2)

Theta can be negative, but the absolute value is constant regardless of which lone is which.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I thought, but that is literally the question word to word.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors parallel to each line are $(1,m_1)$ and $(1,m_2)$. Divide each by its modulus, take the dot product of the unit vectors, you get the $cos$ of the angle between the lines. Or take the modulus of the cross product and you'll get the $sin$.